# iterating through difflib.get_close_matches parameters in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, difflib

I am trying to iterate through the "cutoff" parameter of the difflib.get_close_matches using the following code:

```
import difflib
from numpy import loadtxt

text_file = open('filewithtext.txt', "r")
lines = text_file.read().split(',')

word = 'word_to_search_in_file'

for i in range(0,0.4):
difflib.get_close_matches(word, lines, n=10, cutoff=i)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-224-a5dc535e6b28> in <module>()
2 word = 'word_to_search_in_file'
3 
----> 4 for i in range(0,0.4):
5     difflib.get_close_matches(word, lines, n=10, cutoff=i)

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

My question is - how can iterate through the cutoff parameter, to get the function runs for a list of numbers assigned to the cutoff

Thanks.

Comment: why do you have a float 0.4 in your range rather then 4 ?

Comment: Try changing the range to `range(0,4)` and then change the cutoff value to `cutoff=i/10.0`. It is better not to have floating point numbers in `range` function.

Comment: Thanks for that. 
The problem is that now I don't get error, but I don't get anything else, just an empty return. If I run this function alone ("as is") with no loops, I do get the info for the same parameters.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input of `word` and a sample input of `lines`?

Comment: sample input: create a text file with the word "word_to_search_in_file", name the file "filewithtext.txt"

Then run the code without the loop, and you get a response: "['sampleword']"

If you run it with the loop, you get nothing